# tricky multiline erase in SED

Tags: sed

here is the input:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
```

what I want? do sth like" sed "/ccc/,/(eee)/d" BUT ALSO DELETE "bbb" line (before "ccc")
so that output is:

```
aaa
fff
```

any ideas?

Comment: how come eee is part of the result which you wanted to remove it?

Comment: my mistake, "eee" shall be ommited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with awk, this should do:

```
$ awk '/ccc/,/eee/{if(i!=1){i=1;x="";}next}{if (x)print x;x=$0;}END{print x}' file
aaa
fff
```

Every previous line is printed in the above case. Normal range filtering is done using awk. However, within the range filter, the variable x is reset so that the previous record just before the range is not printed.

**Update**:

sed solution:

```
$ sed '${x;p;};/ccc/,/eee/{/ccc/{s/.*//;x;};d;};1{h;d;};x;/^$/d;' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!{N;/\nccc/!{P;D};/\neee/!ba;d}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a simple 2-pass approach, first pass to identify the lines to delete and the second pass to print only the lines that are not marked for deletion:

```
awk '/ccc/,/eee/{d[NR]=d[NR-1]=1} NR!=FNR && !d[FNR]' file file
```